# Which one is correct grammatically

Tags: grammaticality

Which is better one to begin the speech.

> How's the weather there? Yesterday my friend asked me.

Or

> Yesterday, my friend asked me, "How's the weather there?"

Comment: Is *"How's the weather there?" something your friend is asking you?  If so it should be in quotes.  If you don't put it in quotes, then you are asking the question--not your friend.  And also, whose weather is the friend asking about?  The weather where you are?  Or did your friend ask you about the weather where someone else is, and now you are mentioning to that person the friend asked about them?

Answer (score 1):

We really need more context to answer this question.

If I was on the phone, talking to my daughter who lives a long way away in California, then the first one sounds like a natural way to begin the conversation:

> How's the weather there? Yesterday my friend asked me.

particularly if I had a friend who had asked me a couple days ago, "What's the weather like out where your daughter lives?"

However, you mention a speech. If I was giving a speech to a large audience, it's appropriate to begin with a [hook](http://classroom.synonym.com/write-hook-speech-4061.html), and your second sentence sounds like a better hook to me:

> Yesterday, my friend asked me, "How's the weather there?"

Answer (score -1):

the second answer is more appropriate to start the conversation

Comment: Could you please give a little more explanation as to why it is more appropriate?